# I am having trouble exposing services on home network to the internet

Tags: linux, networking, docker, reverse-proxy

I have a one of those HP mini PCs that I use as a home server and it has some applications running in docker containers. Now I want to share some of these with my friends and communities I am part of but apparently my ISP uses CGNAT and I have no hopes of getting any help from them.

Is there any possible alternative? I have been suggested to set up a reverse proxy but I have no idea how that would work. The resources I have found go too deep into this and seem to cover way more than my use case and are a bit overwhelming for me (networking in general is), any help is appreciated.

I am familiar with Docker and can work with Linux.

P.S. I am willing to pay for a VPS if needed and I have a domain.

Comment: Before getting a vps, I would be looking at a different isp if possible. The sooner IPv4 is retired, the better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're behind CGNAT for IPv4, check whether you have IPv6. This can be used directly by v6-capable clients, and a "reverse proxy" webserver (either on your VPS or a commercial CDN) can accept IPv4 requests and forward them to your server via IPv6.

(Keep in mind that even though IPv6 gives you plenty of external addresses without NAT, they might still be behind a *firewall* on the router or at the ISP.)

If IPv4 is all you have, then *all* remaining options are just variations of setting up an *outgoing* connection to your VPS (or to some service), over which the incoming requests can be tunnelled:

- One option is to set up a VPN (an IP tunnel) such as WireGuard or OpenVPN *from* the home server to your VPS.

  As long as the CGNAT sees the tunnel connection as "alive", this lets the VPS to reach the endpoint that's at home (using the internal addresses of the tunnel interfaces), and through it potentially other home devices as well.

  Once that's in place, the VPS can either run an HTTP(S) reverse proxy that relays requests to the home server via the tunnel, or some similar TCP-level relay, or use DNAT (via iptables) to relay any kind of protocol (e.g. UDP for game servers).

  For example, if the VPN tunnel gets IP addresses 192.168.5.0/24, then Apache or Nginx on the VPS might be configured with `ProxyPass http://192.168.5.2` which would cause it to forward HTTP requests towards your home server, the same concept as what you might already be using with Docker.

  You can also use this together with a second VPN setup for connecting from your phone anywhere, in order to reach your home system via the VPS.

  (Though for that, "mesh" VPNs such as Tailscale or ZeroTier may be more convenient than hand-made tunnels.)
- Another option is a long-lived SSH connection, again from the home server to the VPS, using `-R` reverse tunnels to carry additional TCP connections from the server side towards the SSH client. (This *only* does TCP – not UDP.)

  For example, if you do:

  ```
  $ ssh -R 8080:172.16.5.7:80 myvps
  ```

  ...the VPS now listens on localhost:8080, which can be used as the URL in ProxyPass.

  The reverse tunnels can be either exposed directly (by enabling the "GatewayPorts" option on the server) or used by a reverse proxy running on the VPS. For HTTP(S) the latter would be recommended.

  This is slightly less suitable for "permanent" tunnels in case the connection is lost for any reason, compared to VPN software that's designed to be permanently connected (well, *some* VPN software at least), but it still does the job if you use something like "autossh" or systemd to make sure the connection gets restarted when needed.
- There are commercial services which provide their own relay servers if you run their "agent" software (some support `ssh -R` as well), such as Ngrok and others. Generally those are not quite free, to cover their bandwidth costs, but can be enough for a basic website.

A domain is not necessary for these methods to work (but is certainly better than asking your friends to remember an IP address). The commercial proxy services often give you a randomized subdomain.